# ASP.NET Core - System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type while attempting to activate

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In my ASP.NER Core Web API Project, I have this code:

```
public interface IUriPaginationService
{
    public Uri GetPaginationUri(int page, string actionUrl);
}

public class UriPaginationService : IUriPaginationService
{
    private readonly string _baseUri;
    public UriPaginationService(string baseUri)
    {
        _baseUri = baseUri;
    }
    public Uri GetPaginationUri(int page, string actionUrl)
    {
        string baseUrl = $"{_baseUri}{actionUrl}";
        return new Uri(baseUrl);
    }
}

public abstract class AuditableBaseEntity
{
    public AuditableBaseEntity()
    {
        CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
    }

    [Key]
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public long? LastUpdatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

Repositories:

```
public interface IBaseRepository<T> where T : AuditableBaseEntity
{

    Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAll();
    Task<T> GetById(long id);
    bool EntityExists(long id);
}

public class BaseRepository<T> : IBaseRepository<T> where T : AuditableBaseEntity
{
    private readonly DDMDbContext _context;
    private DbSet<T> _entities;

    public BaseRepository(DDMDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _entities = context.Set<T>();
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAll()
    {
        var list = await _entities.Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false).ToListAsync();
        return list;
    }

    public async Task<T> GetById(long id)
    {
        return await _entities.FindAsync(id);
    }

    public bool EntityExists(long id)
    {
        return _entities.Any(x => x.Id == id && x.IsDeleted == false);
    }
}
```

UnitOfWork:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    IBaseRepository<Merchant> MerchantRepository { get; }
}

public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly DDMDbContext _context;

    public UnitOfWork(DDMDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    private readonly IBaseRepository<Merchant> _merchantRepository;
    public IBaseRepository<Merchant> MerchantRepository => _merchantRepository ?? new BaseRepository<Merchant>(_context);

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_context != null)
        {
            _context.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Services:

```
public interface IMerchantService
{
    public Task<IEnumerable<Merchant>> GetMerchants();
    public bool EntityExists(long id);
    public Task<ResponsePagination<GenericPagination<MerchantGetDto>>> GetAll(int page, int sizeByPage);
}


public class MerchantService : IMerchantService
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private readonly IUriPaginationService _uriPaginationService;
    private readonly DDMDbContext _context;

    public MerchantService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IUriPaginationService uriPaginationService, DDMDbContext context)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _uriPaginationService = uriPaginationService;
        _context = context;
    }
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Merchant>> GetMerchants()
    {
        return await _unitOfWork.MerchantRepository.GetAll();
    }
    public async Task<ResponsePagination<GenericPagination<MerchantGetDto>>> GetAll(int page, int sizeByPage)
    {
        string nextRoute = null, previousRoute = null;
        IEnumerable<Merchant> data = await _unitOfWork.MerchantRepository.GetAll();

        var mapper = new EntityMapper();
        var merchantsDto = data.Select(m => mapper.FromMerchantToMerchantGetDto(m)).ToList();

        GenericPagination<MerchantGetDto> objGenericPagination = GenericPagination<MerchantGetDto>.Create(merchantsDto, page, sizeByPage);
        ResponsePagination<GenericPagination<MerchantGetDto>> response = new ResponsePagination<GenericPagination<MerchantGetDto>>(objGenericPagination);
        response.CurrentPage = objGenericPagination.CurrentPage;
        response.HasNextPage = objGenericPagination.HasNextPage;
        response.HasPreviousPage = objGenericPagination.HasPreviousPage;
        response.PageSize = objGenericPagination.PageSize;
        response.TotalPages = objGenericPagination.TotalPages;
        response.TotalRecords = objGenericPagination.TotalRecords;
        response.Data = objGenericPagination;

        if (response.HasNextPage)
        {
            nextRoute = $"/merchants?page={(page + 1)}";
            response.NextPageUrl = _uriPaginationService.GetPaginationUri(page, nextRoute).ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            response.NextPageUrl = null;
        }

        if (response.HasPreviousPage)
        {
            previousRoute = $"/merchants?page={(page - 1)}";
            response.PreviousPageUrl = _uriPaginationService.GetPaginationUri(page, previousRoute).ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            response.PreviousPageUrl = null;
        }

        return response;
    }

    public bool EntityExists(long id)
    {
        return _unitOfWork.MerchantRepository.EntityExists(id);
    }

    public async Task<Merchant> GetById(long id)
    {
        return await _unitOfWork.MerchantRepository.GetById(id);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[ApiController]
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
public class AdminController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IMerchantService _merchantService;

    public AdminController(MerchantService merchantService)
    {
        _merchantService = merchantService;
    }

    [HttpGet("merchants")]
    public async Task<ResponsePagination<GenericPagination<MerchantGetDto>>> GetAll(int page, int sizeByPage)
    {
        return await _merchantService.GetAll(page, sizeByPage);
    }
}
```

startup:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
//        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddDb(Configuration);
        services.AddJwtAuthentication(Configuration);
        services.AddMvcCoreFramework(Configuration);
        services.AddAppAuthorization(Configuration);

        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();

        services.AddVersioning();

        services.AddSwagger();

        services.AddRouting(options => options.LowercaseUrls = true);

        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddSingleton<IUriPaginationService>(provider =>
        {
            var accesor = provider.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
            var request = accesor.HttpContext.Request;
            var absoluteUri = string.Concat(request.Scheme, "://", request.Host.ToUriComponent());
            return new UriPaginationService(absoluteUri);
        });

        services.AddScoped(typeof(IBaseRepository<>), typeof(BaseRepository<>));
        services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
        services.AddTransient<IMerchantService, MerchantService>();
    }
```

When I use this on postman get request:

> https://localhost:44341/api/v1/merchant/mandates

I got this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'API.Infrastructure.Services.Concrete.MerchantService' while attempting to activate 'API.Web.Controllers.v1.MerchantController'.
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)

How do I resolve this:

Thanks

Comment: where are you doing dependency injection?

Comment: Did you add the service to your Startup.cs ?

Comment: @DiegoBascans - Yes, I have service at startup.cs.  I have updated my code in the post

Comment: I suspect you've got way more code here than is necessary to reproduce your issue. In other words, your code isn't minimal. Please review [mcve]. For example, why do we need to see IUriPaginationService, UriPaginationService, AuditableBaseEntity, IBaseRepository, BaseRepository, IUnitOfWork , and IIUnitOfWork  types? Use the minimal amount of code necessary that  still reproduces your issue. Ideally I should be able to create a new ASP.NET core app on my box, drop in the classes that you gave, and reproduce the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The controller is dependent on the implementation (class)

```
public AdminController(MerchantService merchantService)
{
    _merchantService = merchantService;
}
```

while you registered the abstraction (interface).

```
services.AddTransient<IMerchantService, MerchantService>();
```

Based on the registration it is most likely the controller was meant to be dependent on the interface (abstraction)

```
public AdminController(IMerchantService merchantService) //<-- CHANGED TO INTERFACE
{
    _merchantService = merchantService;
}
```

Updating the controller constructor to be dependent on the registered abstraction will fix the shown exception.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to Nkosi answer, the three injection service are listed below and their scope. three methods define the lifetime of the services

1. AddTransient
   Transient lifetime services are created each time they are requested. This lifetime works best for lightweight, stateless services.
2. AddScoped
   Scoped lifetime services are created once per request.
3. AddSingleton
   Singleton lifetime services are created the first time they are requested (or when ConfigureServices is run if you specify an instance there) and then every subsequent request will use the same instance.

[Brief explation can be found here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/understanding-addtransient-vs-addscoped-vs-addsingleton-in-asp-net-core/)